# Passing ArrayList to a method in java - error "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I tried to pass ArrayList object from mone function to another function but I recived error

```
"cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

the function code as follow:

```
private static void parseHTMLwithJsoup(String outputHTML) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<String> htmlRecords = new ArrayList<String>();

    File in = new File(outputHTML);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in , null);
    Element table = doc.getElementsByTag("table").first();
    Elements trs = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
    for (Element tr : trs) {
        System.out.println("TR: " + tr.text());

        for (Element td : tr.getAllElements()) {
            System.out.println("TD: " + td.text());
            htmlRecords.add(td.text());
            createRDFTriples(htnmlRecords);

        }
    }
    System.out.println();  

}
```

The second function that should recieved the ArrayList object as follow:

```
private static void createRDFTriples(ArrayList<String> rdfTripl){
    Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF); //turns of logging information
....
}
```

Comment: What's the full error? Where does it happen?

Comment: In particular, if you looked closely at the full error, I suspect you'd have found the problem. (Are you sure you want to call `createRDFTriples` *in* the loop rather than *after* the loop, by the way?)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is my bad and I really don't know why this silly mistakes freak me out and took my time !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

"htnmlRecords" is not "htmlRecords."  Simple typo.  Easy to spot.